# Can I put a list of a reference object in the KeySelector in a GroupBy?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, equality

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string PointOfSale { get; set; }

    public List<PurchaseItem> PurchaseItems { get; set; }

    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseItem
{
    public ItemType Type { get; set; } //ItemType is an enum
    public string Subtype { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is group transactions based on where they were conducted and what items were purchased, and sum the cost.

I feel like `GroupBy()` would be the solution here, but I don't know how to make it compare `PurchaseItems` as part of the key, since `PurchaseItem` is a reference type, and specifying an `IEqualityComparer` to `GroupBy()` would have to be able to compare the whole key.

For example:

```
Transaction[] transactions =
{
    new Transaction
    {
        PointOfSale = "Bytes-R-Us",
        PurchaseItems = new List<PurchaseItem>
        {
            new PurchaseItem { ItemType = ItemType.Electronics, Subtype = "peripherals" },
            new PurchaseItem { ItemType = ItemType.Food, Subtype = "candy" }
        },
        Cost = 50.00
    },
    new Transaction
    {
        PointOfSale = "Bytes-R-Us",
        PurchaseItems = new List<PurchaseItem>
        {
            new PurchaseItem { ItemType = ItemType.Electronics, Subtype = "peripherals" },
            new PurchaseItem { ItemType = ItemType.Food, Subtype = "candy" }
        },
        Cost = 25.00
    },
    new Transaction
    {
        PointOfSale = "Bytes-R-Us",
        PurchaseItems = new List<PurchaseItem>
        {
            new PurchaseItem { ItemType = ItemType.Software, Subtype = "games" }
        },
        Cost = 100.00
    },
    new Transaction
    {
        PointOfSale = "The Foo Bar & Grill",
        PurchaseItems = new List<PurchaseItem>
        {
            new PurchaseItem { ItemType = ItemType.Food, Subtype = "fine dining" },
            new PurchaseItem { ItemType = ItemType.Food, Subtype = "liquor" }
        },
        Cost = 75.49
    }
}
```

In this case, I would want to see results saying that I spent $75 on peripherals and candy at Bytes-R-Us, $100 on games at Bytes-R-Us, and $75.49 on food and drink at the Foo Bar & Grill. Something like this:

```
var groupedTransactions = transactions.GroupBy(
    x => new {PointOfSale = x.PointOfSale, Items = x.PurchaseItems},
    y => y.Cost,
    (x, y) => new Transaction
    {
        PointOfSale = x.PointOfSale,
        PurchaseItems = x.Items,
        Cost = y.Sum()
    });
```

But how can I make `x => new {PointOfSale = x.PointOfSale, Items = x.PurchaseItems}` work as I've described?

Comment: Use SelectMany.  I do not know how to get the cost.  Try something like this :             var groupedTransactions = transactions
                .SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseItems.Select(y => new { PointOfSale = x.PointOfSale, Type = y.Type, Subtype = y.Subtype }))
                .GroupBy(x => new { PointOfSale = x.PointOfSale, Items = x.Type, Subtype = x.Subtype })
                .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 steps basically. Firstly flatten your inner `PurchaseItem` collections with `SelectMany`:

```
var result1 = transactions.SelectMany(
        x => x.PurchaseItems,
        (y, z) => new
                      {
                          y.PointOfSale,
                          y.Cost,
                          z.ItemType,
                          z.Subtype
                      })
    .ToList();
```

Then use result of that and `GroupBy` composite key that you needed:

```
var result2 = result1.GroupBy(x => new { x.PointOfSale, x.ItemType, x.Subtype}).ToList();
```

Lastly, consolidate your result set with `Select`:

```
var result3 = result2.Select(
        x => new
                 {
                     PointOfSale = x.Key.PointOfSale,
                     PurchaseItemSubtype = x.FirstOrDefault()?.Subtype,
                     TotalCost = x.Sum(y => y.Cost)
                 })
    .ToList();
```

Serialized version of the final result looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "PointOfSale":"Bytes-R-Us",
      "PurchaseItemSubtype":"peripherals",
      "TotalCost":75.0
   },
   {  
      "PointOfSale":"Bytes-R-Us",
      "PurchaseItemSubtype":"candy",
      "TotalCost":75.0
   },
   {  
      "PointOfSale":"Bytes-R-Us",
      "PurchaseItemSubtype":"games",
      "TotalCost":100.0
   },
   {  
      "PointOfSale":"The Foo Bar & Grill",
      "PurchaseItemSubtype":"fine dining",
      "TotalCost":75.49
   },
   {  
      "PointOfSale":"The Foo Bar & Grill",
      "PurchaseItemSubtype":"liquor",
      "TotalCost":75.49
   }
]
```

I used `ToList()` at the end of each step so that you can step through in debugger and visualize intermediate step results but that is not needed of course. A single linq chain would be:

```
var result = transactions.SelectMany(
        x => x.PurchaseItems,
        (y, z) => new
                      {
                          y.PointOfSale,
                          y.Cost,
                          z.ItemType,
                          z.Subtype
                      })
    .GroupBy(
        x => new
                 {
                     x.PointOfSale,
                     x.ItemType,
                     x.Subtype
                 })
    .Select(
        x => new
                 {
                     PointOfSale = x.Key.PointOfSale,
                     PurchaseItemSubtype = x.FirstOrDefault()?.Subtype,
                     TotalCost = x.Sum(y => y.Cost)
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a string from PurchaseItems and use that as part of the key.
For example if you care only about different Subtype combinations:

```
x => new
{
   PointOfSale = x.PointOfSale,
   Items = string.Join(", ", x.PurchaseItems.OrderBy(p => p.Subtype).Select(p => p.Subtype))
}
```